# Decryption error Length of data to decrypt is invalid

Tags: c#, encryption

I am performing independent encrypt-decrypt (1st app performs enc 2nd decrypts)
While decryption I either get "Padding invalid" or "Length of data to decrypt is invalid" error.Any help is appreciated thanks
My encryption code:

```
static void EncryptFile(string file, string password)
    {
        byte[] passwordBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password);
        byte[] salt = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };

        passwordBytes = SHA256.Create().ComputeHash(passwordBytes);

        RijndaelManaged AES = new RijndaelManaged();
        AES.KeySize = AES.LegalKeySizes[0].MaxSize;
        AES.BlockSize = AES.LegalBlockSizes[0].MaxSize;
        AES.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;

        using (var key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(passwordBytes, salt, 1000)) 
        {
            AES.Key = key.GetBytes(AES.KeySize / 8);
            AES.IV = key.GetBytes(AES.BlockSize / 8);
            AES.Mode = CipherMode.CFB;
        }
        using (FileStream fsCrypt = new FileStream(file + ".ecc", FileMode.Create))
        {

            fsCrypt.Write(salt, 0, salt.Length);
        }

        int bytesToRead = 128 * 1024 * 1024; // 128MB 
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bytesToRead]; // create the array that will be used encrypted
        long fileOffset = 0;
        int read = 0;
        bool allRead = false;

        while (!allRead)
        {
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                fs.Seek(fileOffset, SeekOrigin.Begin); // continue reading from where we were...
                read = fs.Read(buffer, 0, bytesToRead); // read the next chunk
            }

            if (read == 0)
                allRead = true;
            else
                fileOffset += read;

            using (FileStream fsCrypt = new FileStream(file + ".ecc", FileMode.Open)) // automatically dispose fsCrypt
            {
                using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(fsCrypt, AES.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {

                    fsCrypt.Seek(fileOffset, SeekOrigin.End);
                    cs.FlushFinalBlock();
                    cs.Write(buffer, 0, read);

                }
            }
        }

    }
```

and My decryption code:

```
public void DecryptFile(string file,  string password)
    {
        byte[] passwordBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password);
        byte[] salt = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };

        passwordBytes = SHA256.Create().ComputeHash(passwordBytes);

        RijndaelManaged AES = new RijndaelManaged();
        AES.KeySize = AES.LegalKeySizes[0].MaxSize;
        AES.BlockSize = AES.LegalBlockSizes[0].MaxSize;
        AES.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;

        using (var key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(passwordBytes, salt, 1000))
        {
            AES.Key = key.GetBytes(AES.KeySize / 8);
            AES.IV = key.GetBytes(AES.BlockSize / 8);
            AES.Mode = CipherMode.CFB;
        }


        string extension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(file);
        string result = file.Substring(0, file.Length - extension.Length);
        using (FileStream destination = new FileStream(result, FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
        {
            using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(destination, AES.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                try
                {
                    using (FileStream source = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
                    {
                        source.CopyTo(cryptoStream);
                    }
                }
                catch (CryptographicException exception)
                {
                    if (exception.Message == "Padding is invalid and cannot be removed.")
                        throw new ApplicationException("Universal Microsoft Cryptographic Exception (Not to be believed!)", exception);
                    else
                        throw;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you using salts correctly?

Comment: that's what I am confused . Please can you help me..thanks

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/704372/How-to-Use-Rijndael-ManagedEncryption-with-Csharp

Comment: Your whole `while` loop in the encryption could be simplified to `fs.CopyTo(cs);`

Comment: Note that you are not using AES: `AES.BlockSize = AES.LegalBlockSizes[0].MaxSize;` should result in Rijndael with a block size of 256 bits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following calls are executed in the wrong order:

```
cs.FlushFinalBlock();
```

and

```
cs.Write(buffer, 0, read);
```

`FlushFinalBlock` should always come last (it will be automatically called when the stream is closed though, so it should be OK if you don't close the underlying stream first). `FlushFinalBlock` should certainly never be called in a (`while`) loop.

The buffer handling is not correct: the streams should not be closed and opened all the time. Instead a block of bytes should be read, then written to the crypto stream. The `using` statements should be *outside* the `while` loop.

*For CFB mode `PaddingMode.PKCS7` should be set. Padding is not required at all for CFB. Unfortunately .NET seems to have a buggy implementation that **does** require padding to be used in combination to the streams.*

Comment: will try it and update the result..thanks for the reply

Comment: @panman You're welcome, please read the second part I just added.

Comment: so how do you suggest I should do it? actually a bit new to c#

Comment: Could probably be split into more methods. Currently saving under .ext.dec, but I guess you can configure that yourself. Note that you don't need `ProcessFinalBlock` either for stream ciphers such as CFB, but I'll make it work for CBC somewhere tomorrow evening or so and such.

Comment: Code will be included this evening (CET).

Comment: @panman How did you solve it? Because I could only get it working correctly by using PKCS#7 padding, and that *should not be required for CFB*.  Neither None or Zero padding seems to work.

Comment: Actually I changed my code of encryption with this :http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5719/Simple-encrypting-and-decrypting-data-in-C

Comment: If you are trusting any crypto from that site you're already lost. Only 5 star idiots seem to post crypto code there.